# javascript, how to use variable content as variable name?

Tags: javascript, json, variables, dynamic

See please the following code which works fine:

```
var fileContent = app.ReadFile("/sdcard/request-result.json"); // Get JSON content
var count = 0;
var values = JSON.parse(fileContent);
var type = "airTemperature";
console.log(values.hours[count].airTemperature.sg); // this display the right value
```

I would like to use content of type ("airTemperature") instead of airTemperature to get the same result:

```
console.log(values.hours[count].keys(type).sg); // Something like this but this doesn't work!
```

Comment: `values.hours[count][type].sg` ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: You're not trying to use the string as a variable name, you want to use it as a property name. It should be `hours[count][type].sg`